# Unknown type of value in 0,0 while using Google Visuilation Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to display **OHLC** values in Google Visualization candle Stick charts and this is my code

```
var data_value = [
    {
        "date": "2011-08-01",
        "open": "136.65",
        "high": "136.96",
        "low": "134.15",
        "close": "136.49"
    },
    {
        "date": "2011-08-02",
        "open": "135.26",
        "high": "135.95",
        "low": "131.50",
        "close": "131.85"
    },
    {
        "date": "2011-08-05",
        "open": "132.90",
        "high": "135.27",
        "low": "128.30",
        "close": "135.25"
    }
];

 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     data_value
    ], true);

    var options = {
      legend:'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

I am trying to draw Candlestick Charts using Google Charting API .

I have got OHLC data in an array format as shown

But when i am trying to draw the chart , i am getting the  following exception in browser console

**Unknown type of value in 0,0**

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue ??

and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8gcr0xe9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart?hl=en) Data format:

Five or more columns, where the first column defines X-axis values or group labels, and each multiple of four data columns after that defines a different series...

Maybe this helps: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/8gcr0xe9/5/)

```
var data_value = [
[ "2011-08-01", 136.65, 136.96, 134.15, 136.49 ],
[ "2011-08-02", 135.26, 135.95, 131.50, 131.85 ],
[ "2011-08-05", 132.90, 135.27, 128.30, 135.25 ]
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to answer the question .